# Create JSON from SQL Query using PHP

Tags: php, json

I am attempting to output JSON in the following format:

```
[{
  "category": "cONTIME",
  "value": 155,
  "color": "#0f9b0f"
},{
  "category": "cLATE",
  "value": 244,
  "color": "#dd1818"
},{
  "category": "cTOTAL",
  "value": 399,
  "color": "#0575E6"
},{
  "category": "ONTIME",
  "value": 60,
  "color": "#0f9b0f"
},{
  "category": "LATE",
  "value": 58,
  "color": "#dd1818"
},{
  "category": "TOTAL",
  "value": 118,
  "color": "#0f9b0f"
}]
```

The stored procedure I am executing returns the following table - This is SQL SERVER - I have greyed over the columns that are not of interest

[image]

I have attempted this by using

```
$categories = [
    'cONTIME' => $row['cONTIME'],
    'cLATE' => [],
    'cTOTAL' => [],
];
$colors = [
    'ONTIME' => "#0f9b0f",
    'LATE' => "#dd1818",
    'TOTAL' => "#0575E6",
];

$json = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $json['category'] = $categories;
        $json['value'] = $row;
        $json['color'] = $colors;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Returning this:

```
{
   "category":{
      "cONTIME":null,
      "cLATE":[

      ],
      "cTOTAL":[

      ]
   },
   "value":{
      "cTOTAL":399,
      "cONTIME":155,
      "cLATE":244,
      "cPERCENTS":38,
      "TOTAL":118,
      "ONTIME":60,
      "LATE":58,
      "PERCENTS":50,
      "KPI":"UP"
   },
   "color":{
      "ONTIME":"#0f9b0f",
      "LATE":"#dd1818",
      "TOTAL":"#0575E6"
   }
}
```

I have also attempted this:

```
$json = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {          
        $json[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Returning:

```
[
   {
      "cTOTAL":399,
      "cONTIME":155,
      "cLATE":244,
      "cPERCENTS":38,
      "TOTAL":118,
      "ONTIME":60,
      "LATE":58,
      "PERCENTS":50,
      "KPI":"UP"
   }
]
```

As well as the above I have tried numerous other methods & examples but can't seem to achieve the format I need. I am fully aware of PDO, Prepared Statements, Injection etc!, I just need to format the JSON first, but thanks in advance for the advice

Any help would be greatly appreciated - PHP Noob

Comment: So the colors are a hardcoded list/array?

Comment: Are the column names supposed to become your categories?

Comment: So all you are getting from the database is this one single row? Then you don’t want to loop over the records in the result set to begin with (no need to _loop_ anything for a total “iteration count” of _one_), but you want to loop over the _columns_ of this one single record to begin with.

Comment: You can't use `'cONTIME' => $row['cONTIME'],` _before_ you've defined the `$row`-array. That will _always_ give you `null` (and a warning in your error log about undefined variable).

Comment: @PatrickQ Yeah - those  colours are hardcoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$json = array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {          
    foreach ($row as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {
        if (in_array($fieldName, ['cTOTAL', 'cONTIME', 'cLATE', 'TOTAL' ,'ONTIME', 'LATE'])) {
            $json[] = [
                "category" => $fieldName,
                "value" => $fieldValue,
                "color" => getColorByFieldName($fieldName),
            ];
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($json);

function getColorByFieldName($fieldName) 
{
    if ($fieldName === 'ONTIME' || $fieldName === 'cONTIME') {
        return '#0f9b0f';
    }
    if ($fieldName === 'LATE' || $fieldName === 'cLATE') {
        return '#dd1818';
    }
    if ($fieldName === 'TOTAL' || $fieldName === 'cTOTAL') {
        return '#0575E6';
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing `#` in front of the middle color :-)

Comment: soz - was using the app - cheers @u_mulder - that worked a charm